# RIDE.py for RobotFramework won't let me type more than one letter

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am using RIDE IDE for Robot Framework, however whenever I try to type in a cell in the test menu, it only lets me type one letter. any subsequent letters just reaplce the previous letters. My keyboard is not on insert mode. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any details about Operating System, Python and RIDE's versions, so it is very hard to help you.

My guess is that you are using RIDE with wxPython 4.1, and not the recommended version, 4.0.7.post2.
If this is the case, then you should go to the [project page](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE) and read README.adoc or the F.A.Q. at wiki.